# stringwithformat issue in string searching

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, stringwithformat, nsrange

I did following experiment. Can any one point out why strings initialized with stringwithformat fail in string searching?

```
    NSString *test1 = @"Hello";
    NSString *test2 = @"Hello";
    NSString *test3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ", test2];

   NSRange titleResultsRange = [test1 rangeOfString:test2 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

I get `titleResultsRange.length > 0`

But when I do  -

`NSRange titleResultsRange = [test1 rangeOfString:test3 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];`

I get `titleResultsRange.length = 0`

Why?

Comment: Note that `test3` has an extra white space.

Comment: Yes, even then NSRange.length should be greater than 0. As there is a substring match. Do you get the same result?

Comment: There is no match since `test3` is not a substring of `test1` because, as I said earlier, `test3` has an extra white space. Maybe you’re confusing the receiver and the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that test3 is "Hello " not "Hello".

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *test1 = @"Hello";
NSString *test2 = @"Hello";
NSString *test3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", test2];
NSRange titleResultsRange = [test1 rangeOfString:test2 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
```

Try now. In your code test3 string contain extra white space.